# How could i draw a line between a treeview item and a cusom control in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, drawing

I am trying to write a new application.it has a source treeview,and a button in another stack panel.
i would like to draw a line between selected treeview item and the button i have mentioned.
i don't know how could i do it.
it would be garteful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)

HTH :)